# Discuss compactness of the set of $L^2$ bounded functions

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compactness

> Discuss weak and strong compactness of the following subsets of $L^2(0,1)$:
>
> $A=\{u\in L^2(0,1):||u||_{L^2}\le1\}.$

I know some theorems which might be helpful, but I don't know if I applied them correctly.

The set $A$ is a closed unit ball of the Banach space $L^2(0,1)$, which is an infinite dimensional normed space, so by Riesz theorem $A$ is not strongly compact. Moreover, since $L^2(0,1)$ is reflexive, by Banach-Alaoglu theorem its closed unit ball $A$ is weakly compact.

Is this correct?

Comment: Well, in this case $n=1$. You will also need the Poincaré's inequality to control the $L^2$ norm in terms of the $L^2$ norm of the derivative.

Comment: Riesz' lemma does the job, but for Hilbert spaces it's even simpler. Just take any orthonormal sequence $(e_n)$. Since $\| e_n-e_m\|=1$ for $n\neq m$, it can't have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @MaoWao very good example thank you, so thats prove that the set is not strongly compact, what about weak compact? Can you use the orthonormal sequence in this case too?

Comment: You can, although I don't like it that much. An orthonormal basis incuces an isomorphism $L^2(0,1)\to\ell^2$. On bounded subsets of $\ell^2$, weak convergence is equivalent to pointwise convergence (since finitely supported sequences are dense in $\ell^2$). To extract a pointwise convergent subsequence is elementary, just apply the usual diagonal argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning point A, you solved it correctly via "abstract nonsense". However, I think that it is always better to use concrete examples when possible.

In this case, a concrete example of a sequence contained in $A$ that has no converging subsequences is
$$
f_n(x)=\sqrt n f(nx), $$ 
where $f$ is any nonzero element of $A$.

> **Here I omitted an important piece of information**.
>   The function $f$ is defined on $[0, 1]$, but we implicitly consider that $$f(x)=0,\qquad \text{if }x\notin [0,1].$$ 
>   In particular, for all $x\ne 0$, it holds that $nx>1$ for all sufficiently large $n$, and so $f(nx)=0$ eventually. Therefore 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)= 0,$$ 
>   and so $f_n\to 0$ pointwise almost everywhere.

Now the change of variable formula for integrals yields $$\tag{1}\|f_n\|_{L^2}=\|f\|_{L^2},\qquad \forall n\ge 1;$$ 
so $f_n\in A$ for all $n$. Now suppose for a contradiction that there exists $g\in L^2$ and a subsequence $f_{k_n}$ such that $$\|f_{k(n)}-g\|_{L^2}\to 0.$$ 
By (1), it must be that $\|g\|_{L^2}=\|f\|_{L^2}\ne 0$; thus, $$g\ne 0.$$ However, any sequence that converges in $L^2$ has a subsequence that converges pointwise almost everywhere, so there exists a sub-sub-sequence $f_{k(h(n))}$ such that 
$$
f_{k(h(n))}\to g,\qquad \text{almost everywhere.}$$
And this is a contradiction, for $f_{k(h(n))}\to 0$ almost everywhere by the remark in the colored box, and so it would imply that $g=0$.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain what's consequence of having a bounded sequence contained in $A$ that has no converging subsequences?

Comment: @soundwave: That contradicts the very definition of compactness.

Comment: Ok thankjs, and why if the limit of $f_n$ is $0$ pointwise, it cannot exist a subsequence with limit $0$ too?

Comment: @soundwave: I really think you should try harder; these are questions with an immediate answer. Think about equation (1).

Comment: From (1) i get that $||f_n-f||_{L^2}=0\ \forall n$, so $f_n\to f$? But then you said that pointwise limit of $f_n$ is $0$ and I dont understand why.

Comment: @soundwave: Fair enough, that's a rightful question and I'll answer it with a edit.

Comment: Thank i'm reading, in the box did you mean "In particular, for all $x\notin [0,1]$, it holds that" ?

Comment: @soundwave: No. I truly mean what I wrote, I double-checked.

Comment: Ah, could you please write the computation of the limit? I'm really confused, take $x=n^{-1/2}$, then $f_n(x)=\sqrt{n}f(\sqrt{n})$. As $n$ goes to infinity $f$ goes to $0$ as fast as $\sqrt{n}$ goes to infinity, so who win?

Comment: I wrote it. If the argument of $f$ is outside $[0, 1]$ then $f$ vanishes.

Comment: Ok, but why the limit is $0$ for all $x\ne0$? What about $x\in(0,1)?$